# container not accessible when using --network host

Tags: docker, networking

I am writing a simple nodejs container to forward requests on localhost to a port, the container exposes port 4433

```
docker build . -t myproxy
```

when i run the container by publishing ports like

```
docker run --rm -p 4433:4433 myproxy
```

I am able to access my server through http://localhost:4433 as expected but if i try to run the container with --network host i.e

```
docker run --rm --net host myproxy
```

I cannot access the container and get site cannot be reached error.
why is container not binding to my host network?
if i provide both options i.e.

```
docker run --rm --net host -p 4433:4433 myproxy
```

then i do get warning on console that
`WARNING: Published ports are discarded when using host network mode` which means it does recognize that i am trying to use host network.

OS: MAC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/):

> The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server.